# Javascript (jQuery) module/library loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, sinemacula

As many of you will be aware, Google offers an API whereby you can load particular modules/libraries by calling a simple function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.2");
</script>
```

I am currently in the process of developing my own library of code of which I would like to distribute amongst my websites easily and efficiently and I cannot think of a better method than the one above.

However, I am not too sure what the best way of writing the code for this is. Obviously my library will be an object, so will start with something like this (I think, correct me if I am wrong):

```
function company(){
    this.load = function(modules){
        // Modules is an array of modules to load
        // Load the separate modules here
        // from external files in their minified format
    }
}

var company = new company;
company.load(['forms']);
```

Is the above method the right way to go? How do I then load in the modules from separate files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around and gaining experience from others, I figured the following was the best method. *Others may disagree, feel free to comment*

```
/**
 * Sine Macula Javascript API
 * The Sine Macula API contains all base functions for use throughout
 * all websites
 * @name class.sinemacula.js
 * @author Ben Carey
 * @version 1.0
 * @date 25/10/2012
 * @copyright (c) 2012 Sine Macula Limited (sinemaculammviii.com)
 */

function SineMacula(){

    // Only proceed if jQuery has been loaded
    if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){
        // jQuery has not been loaded
        console.log('jQuery has not been loaded');
    }else{

        /**
         * Sine Macula Load
         * Load the Sine Macula Libraries and Plugins
         * into the current document
         *
         * The options:
         * - package: the package of libraries to load
         * - packageURL: a remote source to load the package details from
         * - libraries: any additional libraries to load
         *
         * @param object options The options for the Sine Macula load
         */
        this.load = function(options){
            var url,query,script;
            // Set the defaults for the loader
            var options = $.extend({
                package:    'none', // Do not load any packages by default
                packageURL: false, // Do not retrieve the package details from a URL by default
                libraries:  [] // Do not load any libraries by default
            },options);
            // Build the query based on the parameters supplied
            if(options.packageURL){
                // Build the query to allow for a remote
                // package definition
                query = '?packageURL='+encodeURIComponent(options.packageURL);
            }else if(options.package=='none'){
                query = '?libraries='+encodeURIComponent(options.libraries.join());
            }else{
                query = encodeURIComponent(options.package)+'/?libraries='+encodeURIComponent(options.libraries.join());
            }
            // Complete the url by appending the query
            url = '//libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/'+query;
            // Append the script tag to the end of the document
            script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = url;
            $('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the [CommonJS Module](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) spec.  Then you can load them with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html).

Comment: Guessing the site is temporarily down, but 'commonJs' link is not working, nor are links from Google to their site. Regardless, I get the idea, although I don't quite understand how it will work. It will not know where to load my modules from etc. I probably need to see their site so cannot really comment at this point

Comment: Ah, I thought you were asking a "how do I write / load modules" question, when you're also asking how to *distribute* them.  If you have a mechanism to make sure the files are in the same place relative to each site's root, you can [configure RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages) to point to e.g. `/scripts/` then call `require(["foo", "bar"])`.

Comment: Is there any point using the requireJS plugin when it probably contains hundreds of lines code when in fact I probably wont need more than 50? In other words, there will be a lot of functionality in the requireJS plugin that I will not use and therefore will just be wasted resource, which will in turn, defeat the point of me doing this. I am trying to load these modules separately so that I do not keep them all in one file, and therefore use less resources :-)

Comment: Well, Jeff says [programmers are expensive](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html), but you're welcome to reinvent just the parts of the wheel you need :D

Comment: I agree in most cases, but here, it really seems that it is unnecessary to include all that code, when the whole point of doing this is to reduce the resources needed etc :-). What I effectively need to know is what is the best way to load javascript pages dynamically. Is it as simple as placing a script tag (via jQuery) in the header?

Comment: I think so, yeah -- if you dig down deep enough, that's all that these libraries are doing under the hood.

Comment: Interesting, if I am placing these in dynamically then how do I know when the files have successfully loaded?

Comment: I *think* that if you put your `require` statements in global scope, and your business logic inside a `document.ready` handler (i.e. wrap in `$()`), you're guaranteed to have all the scripts loaded before your code executes, but I can't cite chapter and verse to prove that it's true.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, all my initiating functions are executed after `$(document).ready`, and the loading will be done before this so logically it should work, but will not know without testing